# Setting server timezone to add/subtract time from date

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, date

I have users that set their timezone when they create their account.  Their account can expire after so many days and the user is able to search for accounts expiring on X day. When the search is run it uses the browser's timezone instead of the users timezone. I have set the timezone like so:

```
CountryDAO countryDao = new CountryDAO();
String timezone = countryDao.findTimezone(advisor.getPlannerID());
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezone));
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat();
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
```

this code does not set the time zone to the server.  I use datapicker to select the date and search but it still uses GMT and not the timezone that is set.

How do I use the time zone that is set?

Answer (score 1):

As the [correct answer by Meno Hochschild](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20891229/642706), `java.util.TimeZone.setDefault()` is a static method affecting your entire JVM. Not what you want.

Avoid using java.util.Date & Calendar classes. They are badly designed and implemented.

Instead, use the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library to manipulate your date-times. Nearly all of Joda-Time is immutable and thread-safe. So it is good for use in servlets & JSP.

Generally you want to work in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)/GMT, meaning no time zone offset. When presenting to the user, then localize to a particular time zone, format, and language.

I don't know how you are doing it, but it seems that you are determining the user's time zone. Good. (a) Be sure your time zone string is a [name of a time zone](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html) rather than the outmoded 3-letter code. Those 3-letter codes are neither standardized nor unique. (b) If you are using some kind of JavaScript or other trick to detect and report system settings on the client machine, consider offering the user a way to select a time zone as well. The user may be "thinking" in one time zone while their machine is set for another.

Use that time zone name string to instantiate a DateTimeZone in Joda-Time. Pass that timeZone as an argument to various Joda-Time methods.

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forId( timeZoneName );
```

In Joda-Time, a DateTime knows its own time zone (in contrast to a java.util.Date). If you do not specify a time zone, you get the JVM's default time zone. Big tip: Always specify a time zone rather than rely on default, to avoid surprises when running in production.

```
DateTime dateTimeInUTC = new DateTime( DateTimeZone.UTC );
DateTime dateTimeInParis = dateTimeInUTC.toDateTime( DateTimeZone.forId( "Europe/Paris" ) );
```

You can add and subtract years, months, days, hours, and such in Joda-Time. And comparison methods test if dates come before or after each other. To find the beginning of a day, call `withTimeAtStartOfDay` (do not just set hours to zero, as not all days in all zones start at midnight).

```
DateTime aWeekAgoDateTime = new DateTime( timeZone ).withTimeAtStartOfDay().minusWeeks( 1 ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
…
boolean isMoreThanWeekOld = someDateTime.isBefore( aWeekAgoDateTime );
```

Beyond that, I cannot help any more. Your question is not clear. What search? A database? An array or other collection? In JavaScript on client? In Java on server?

Answer (score 0):

`TimeZone.setDefault(...)` is statically setting the time zone of the JVM (here on the server) for all users. I assume you rather want to set the time zone of the current user session. If so, then you need a special jsp session attribute where you store and read the time zone preference of the user.